# 403 Forbidden - sharepoint APIs

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, authentication, sharepoint-rest-api, postman

I am facing a strange issue with the access to SharePoint APIs using an access token.

I have generated the `tenantid` and `client_id` using the below URL

```
https://<site-name>.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/client.svc/

realm="xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-a0b4-xxxxxxxx",client_id="xxxxxxx-0000-xxxx-ce00-000000000000"
```

and after generating the above details I got the access token using below url:

```
https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/<tenant_id>/tokens/OAuth/2
```

and when the access token is ready and tried making a call to the rest through postman

```
API-https://<site-name>.sharepoint.com/_api/web?$select=Title
```

I am getting the below error

> Issue :  403 Forbidden- The request is a legal request, but the server
>   is refusing to respond to it. Unlike a 401 Unauthorized response,
>   authenticating will make no difference

Please let me know how i need to proceed from here.

For more info: I followed this blog to setup everything:
http://www.ktskumar.com/2017/01/access-sharepoint-online-using-postman/

Comment: Yes, go ahead. Based on the article you have to add some request header values to the API request.